# zip each file in a folder with max. 100 MB and use random names for the zip file

Tags: command-line, zip, rar, total-commander

is there a way or multiple ways how to zip the files in each folder and save it with a random chosen name?

An example would be: i have three main folders with names A, B, C. Each folder contains a couple of files. And i want to zip all the files in each folder and save the zipped files in the same folder accordingly. However, it shouldn't be one big zipped file in the folders but splitted in multiple zipped files e.g. with a size of max. 100 MB for each zipped file.

This could probably be done by using the command line. However, are there any other ways such as by using the tool "Total Commander" etc.

Thank you

Comment: zip the whole folder into one zip file, or zip each file individually? In windows powershell, you can do a pretty simple `Compress-Archive -Path "C:\folder\folderA\" -DestinationPath "C:\folder\A.zip"` for each of your main folders

Comment: The aim is to zip all files in each folder so that at the end you have, in each folder, the zipped files. Because the files are large there shouldn't be one big zipped file in the folder but splitted in multiple zipped files with a size of e.g. 100MB . Your suggenstion looks simple. I could do that. I could prepare the links in excel with random names and fire it up all at once in powershall. I just thought there might be a program for it to handle, thanks @Cpt.Whale

Comment: Hello, your comment is quite different compared to the initial question. Please state what is needed specifically, including which system you're using and why don't you want to use CLI.

Comment: Hint: if names are simply random, eventually you would have a collision of two with the same name. First make an *ordered* list, then switch pairs of elements in all to ensure no repeat.

Comment: Hi @Destroy666, i have updated my question, thank you for your suggestion. And using CLI would also be fine as long as it does the job.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : IF there is a risk of that happing, perhaps the best way is to specify the names in advance. With more than 100 Folders to zip that might take a while however one quick solution would be to use excel for generating the random names and check it for collision names.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things, you could just set a predefined name and increment a postfix number for each new file. Your question still isn't fully clear either. Is the 100MB a maximum? What's the point of chunking the zip files to be around that size? The title mismatches question content.

Comment: @Destroy666: I will try that with a command line in powershell. I guess it won't be that complicated. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I guess I managed to solve the problem by myself: The attached code allows compressing subfolders within a specified main folder. It sets a maximum file size limit of 400 MB for each compressed archive. Certain paths are excluded from compression. The compressed RAR files are saved in a specified destination folder.

The code iterates through each subfolder in the main folder and compresses them individually while preserving the order in which the subfolders appear, instead of sorting them alphabetically. For each subfolder, a random name is generated for the RAR file, and the compression path is set accordingly.

All files within each subfolder are gathered, and the command-line arguments for WinRAR are constructed accordingly. WinRAR is launched as a separate process to compress the subfolder. If an error occurs during compression, an error message is displayed, and the user is prompted to continue.

The entire process is repeated for each subfolder. Finally, a success message is displayed if all RAR files were created successfully.

It is important to adjust the provided paths and settings according to your specific requirements.

```
 $sourcePath = "D:\FINISH"
 $maxFileSize = 100MB

 $excludePaths = @("C:\Users\Yavuz\AppData", "C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles")
 $destinationPath = "D:\Test"

 $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Directory | Where-Object { 
 $_.FullName - 
 notin $excludePaths }

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
$folderPath = $folder.FullName

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $folderPath)) {
    Write-Host "Folder does not exist: $folderPath"
    Continue
}

$randomName = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName().Substring(0, 12)
$rarPath = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath "$randomName.rar"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File

$commandArgs = @("a", "-r", "-ep1", "-s", "-v400m", "-m0", "-ma5", "-md128m", "- 
mm=", "-ierr", "`"$rarPath`"", "`"$folderPath\*`"")

$process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" - 
ArgumentList $commandArgs -PassThru -WindowStyle Normal -WorkingDirectory 
$folderPath
$process.WaitForExit()

if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    Write-Host "Error compressing the folder: $folderPath"
    Read-Host "Press any key to continue..."
}
}Write-Host "RAR files were created successfully."
```